# Keras: Custom Layer with Matrix Multiplication Gives Dimension Error When it Should be Correct

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a custom keras layers that takes in multiple vectors of the same size (eg: a list of 3 input vectors, each with length 10. In keras, the shape of each input vector will be (?, 10).)

In the custom layer under the call section, I first stack the 3 vectors to form a shape (?, 3, 10), where each vector becomes a row vector and the 3 vectors combine to form a matrix, x (excluding the batch dimension).

Then, x is multiplied by a weight matrix, w, that is of size (3,3) with no batch dimension. The weight matrix is defined in the build part of the custom layer.

The result y is permutated to make the batch dimension the first dimension again.

Lastly, the layer must output 3 vectors of the same length as the original input. So I slice the along axis=1 to give 3 tensors each of same size (?,10).

I tried out a test case and it seems to work. But when I call the model and have a line for model.summary(), it gives the following error:
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 0 for 'add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [3,3], [0].

I have tried various solutions including K.batch_dot() but for batch_dot() I could not get it to work due to dimension errors again...

Thank you for your help!

## Solved

Replace

```
self.trainable_weights = self._w
```

with

```
self.trainable_weights.append(self._w)
```

Phew

```
# Test Case
import keras.backend as K
a = K.variable(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
b = K.variable(np.repeat(np.array([[1,1,10,1,1],[2,2,20,2,2],[3,3,30,3,3]])[np.newaxis,:],repeats=10,axis=0))
c = K.dot(a,b)
c = K.permute_dimensions(c,pattern=(1,0,2))
y = K.eval(c)
print(y)
print(c.shape)  # (10, 3, 5)

# Custom layer build part
def build(self, input_shape):
    # input_shape should be a list, since cross stitch must take in inputs from all the individual tasks.
    self._input_count = len(input_shape)
    w = np.identity(self._input_count) * 0.9
    inverse_diag_mask = np.invert(np.identity(self._input_count, dtype=np.bool))
    off_value = 0.1 / (self._input_count - 1)
    w[inverse_diag_mask] = off_value
    self._w = K.variable(np.array(w))
    self.trainable_weights = self._w

    super(CrossStitchLayer, self).build(input_shape)

# Custom layer call part
def call(self, x, **kwargs):
    temp = x  # to show shape
    x = K.stack(x, axis=1)
    y1 = K.dot(self._w, x)
    y = K.permute_dimensions(y1, pattern=(1, 0, 2))
    results = []
    for idx in range(self._input_count):
        results.append(y[:, idx, :])
    return results
```

## Full Error Message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1628, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 0 for 'add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [3,3], [0].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/limka/Desktop/Python/strain_sensor/run_cross_validation.py", line 10, in <module>
    k_folds=10, k_shuffle=True, save_model=False, save_model_name=None, save_model_dir='./save/models/')
  File "C:\Users\limka\Desktop\Python\strain_sensor\own_package\cross_validation.py", line 57, in run_skf
    model = MTmodel(fl=ss_fl, mode=model_mode, hparams=hparams, labels_norm=True)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Desktop\Python\strain_sensor\own_package\models.py", line 217, in __init__
    cs_model = cross_stitch(self.features_dim, self.labels_dim, self.hparams)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Desktop\Python\strain_sensor\own_package\models.py", line 193, in cross_stitch
    model.summary()
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1260, in summary
    print_fn=print_fn)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\layer_utils.py", line 166, in print_summary
    print_layer_summary_with_connections(layers[i])
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\layer_utils.py", line 153, in print_layer_summary_with_connections
    layer.count_params(),
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1129, in count_params
    return count_params(self.weights)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1022, in weights
    return self.trainable_weights + self.non_trainable_weights
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 856, in _run_op
    return getattr(ops.Tensor, operator)(a._AsTensor(), *args)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 878, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 300, in add
    "Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1792, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "C:\Users\limka\Anaconda3\envs\my-rdkit-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1631, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 3 and 0 for 'add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [3,3], [0].
```

Comment: `dot` is weird and you should probably get better results with `tf.matmul`. Look closely at the dimensions of the inputs and outputs of `dot` and other operations to see if they are really the size you expect.

Comment: You should use `self.add_weight` to have a trainable weight. See the [tutorial](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/)

Comment: @ Daniel Moller I tried using self.add_weight as the weight matrix and for some magical reason it works... I don't understand why it will be so even though my custom layer seems to be exactly the same... Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ Daniel Moller Okay I found out the reason why the original custom weight did not work. It is because of the way I defined the self.trainable_weights. I will add the answer as an edit to my question. Thank you!